# How to delete message upon reaction discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This code errors no matter how I change it, and I just want it to delete the message upon receiving "" reaction.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
    message.delete(0500);
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that `message` is defined. If the code is erroring, you should read the error, look at the stack trace and [debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) _before_ [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

To delete a message upon reaction use the `reaction.message.delete()` method. This accesses the message that the reaction refers to, and deletes it.